# How to explicitly disable buttons angular

Tags: javascript, angular

Hi I have a set of buttons as below,

```
let Btns: Array<any> = [{
    type: "submit",
    BtnType: "prev",
    label: "Previous",
    class: "btn-outline",
    icon: "kd-back",
    disabled: false
},
{
    type: "submit",
    BtnType: "next",
    label: "Next",
    icon: "kd-play",
    class: "btn-text",
    disabled: false
}];
```

Also I have two variables:

```
private nextBtn_disabled: boolean = false;
private prevBtn_disabled: boolean = true;
```

I am implementing a disable feature to the buttons. The behaviour is something like this:

1. prev button must be disabled when the page first loads
2. next button must be disabled when meet certain condition also must be disabled when the user click prev

The following is my HTML:

```
<div class="form-group text-center">
    <button *ngFor="let btn of Btns" [type]="(btn.type=='submit')?'submit':'button'" class="btn btn-icon" [ngClass]="btn.class" (click)="_btnClick(btn, _finalConfig)" [disabled]="nextBtn_disabled">
        <i *ngIf="btn.BtnType!='next'" [class]="btn.icon"></i>
        <span>{{btn.label}}</span>
        <i *ngIf="btn.BtnType=='next'" [class]="btn.icon"></i>
    </button>
</div>
```

How can I achieve it? I tried `||` condition and `&&` condition between `nextBtn_disabled` and  `prevBtn_disabled`. But didnt work. Any idea guys? Thanks in advance.

Comment: || condition didn't work because the prev button by default is always disabled.

Comment: if you only have two buttons, why need the array and `ngFor`? Just define them directly in the HTML template, then you don't have the complexity defining a button that has two 'modes'

Comment: no it will be many as per the user

Comment: When do you want the prev button enabled? It sounds like if you want to do it this way you'll need `[disabled]` to be bound to the disabled variable for the button type .. e.g. `[disabled]="(preBtn_disabled && btn.BtnType == 'prev') || (nextBtn_disabled && btn.BtnType == 'next')".
If you have extra variables for each button, this will get _really_ messy if you have more buttons so I'd look at a different way of defining the template.

Answer (score 6):

I would recommend something like this.

```
<button [disabled]="isInvalid()">Your html</button>

isInvalid() {
   return (checkCondition_to_be_met || clicked_on_prev_button);
}
```

Comment: Pramod, I have two buttons how can i handle the disable property for each of them with this methood

Comment: So your code needs to meet the following conditions. prev button must be disabled when the page first loads. next button must be disabled when meet certain condition also must be disabled when the user clicks prev.so for your first condition to be satisfied, for the prev button, set [disabled]="prev_btn_disabled", where prev_btn_disabled=true.
And for the second condition to be met, give your [disabled] a function that automatically checks for updates where there is a change in models. Function return a boolean value, by evaluating your condition to be met

Comment: The tricky part is i need to make the prev_btn by default disabled

Comment: <button [disabled]="!isValid"></button>, and set your isValid to false, by default it will disable it.

Answer (score 1):

Code it like this:

check it for your 2nd point (next button must be disabled when meet certain condition also must be disabled when the user click prev)

Html code:

```
<div>
<button *ngFor="let btn of btns" [disabled]="btn.disabled"      (click)="btnClick(btn,btns)">{{btn.label}}</button>
</div>
```

Add other html code according to your need.

Component code:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';


@Component({
    selector: 'app-root',
    templateUrl: './app.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
 })
export class AppComponent {


btn1 :boolean = false;
btn2 :boolean = false;

btns: Array<any> = [
    {
        type: "submit",
        BtnType: "prev",
        label: "Previous",
        class: "btn-outline",
        icon: "kd-back",
        disabled: this.btn1
    },
    {
        type: "submit",
        BtnType: "next",
        label: "Next",
        icon: "kd-play",
        class: "btn-text",
        disabled: this.btn2
    }];


    btnClick(btn,btns){

        var certain_condition = true; //put your code for any certain condition here and make it true or false.
        if((btn.label === "Previous") || certain_condition){
            console.log(btns[1]);
            btns[1].disabled = true;
        }

    }

  }
```

For your first point make "btn1 :boolean = true;"
Try changing various conditions according to your need.